# Issue "SSL certificate" when downloading and installing symfony 3

Tags: symfony

Please how to solve this problem ?

[image: please How to solve this problem ? thanks ..]

Thanks ..

Comment: [The doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications) describes this, please download and enable the proper certificate

Answer (score 0):

Link only answers might disappear. Here are the steps for reference:

1. Download a file with the updated list of certificates from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Move the downloaded cacert.pem file to some safe location in your system
3. Update your php.ini file and configure the path to that file:

> ```
> ; Linux and macOS systems
> curl.cainfo = "/path/to/cacert.pem"
>
> ; Windows systems
> curl.cainfo = "C:\path\to\cacert.pem"
> ```